# Extending a Doctrine entity to add extra association mapping in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance

I currently have a User Doctrine entity and model in my Components.  I have a User Bundle that does the basics of working with users, CRUD, etc.

I am developing a resource allocation bundle and I want to extend my User entity to add extra associations without changing the original user. Then the ResourceAllocation Bundle will be completely separate from the User Bundle.

I have setup a mapped superclass of BaseUser, which both User and SkilledUser (the one from the Resource Allocation Bundle). This however, tries to create a table for both User and SkilledUser which is undesired.

The user and skilled user could be the same user, so, Single Table Inheritance is not going to work.

Effectively, the end result should be one table with the users in.

We are working in YAML if answers could keep to this method, that would be great.

Comment: So how about extending it like that `class SkilledUser extends User {}`?

Comment: Would user then have to be a mapped superclass also in that case?

Answer (score 0):

"Effectively, the end result should be one table with the users in."

The only way to achieve this is with STI (Single Table Inheritance).

"The user and skilled user could be the same user, so, Single Table Inheritance is not going to work."

I don't see how this matters... you can still create an association between User and SkilledUser if that is what you mean here.

See reference: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: Isn't the idea of STI to use a discriminator column, e.g. Worker extends Person, Manager extends Person would result in doctrine putting a column in to mark Worker and Manager as different. This is not the same as just adding some associations to the Person for use in one bundle without affecting the original bundle.

Comment: Correct. You cannot have a single row be both a User and a SkilledUser at the same time, as far as I am aware. Nor am I sure why you would want to. Why not look at FOSUserBundle and see how they allow you to replace the UserBundle's User entity with you own? By the way, I think composition probably fits with what you want to do better (ie, for some User's you can make an association to a SkilledUser, effectively allowing them to be either just a User, or a User that also has a SkilledUser association.

Comment: I was trying to not have to add configuration to the original User. What I have done so far is just associate a user and their skills through a separate table and then get users by grouping on the userid. It is not ideal because I have to get the user from the userSkills entity rather than directly being able to do $user->getSkills(); Instead it will have to be $userSkill->getUser()->getSkills().